How are multiple DDR5 DIMMs wired into to the same channel?
This question is about how multiple DDR5 DIMMs in the same memory channel are wired to the processor. This is mostly an electrical engineering question, and the goal to answer this question:
Will re-seating a processor increase the likelihood that the second DIMM per channel will function, specifically in the case when both memory channels are known to function populated with only one DIMM each (ie, both memory channels are functional)? All memory modules are known good.
I looked around at DDR5 documentation and there is quite a bit related to performance and ranks, but none that I could find about how they are physically wired to their memory bus in the layout.
My thinking is this: if the channels are each independent, and a series of memory modules on the same channel is wired as a parallel bus (with some kind of chip- or address-selector), then reseating the processor is unlikely to solve the problem when both channels are known to function.  Is this true?
I have an AM5 system that sees the memory in one DIMM slot of each memory channel for the processor, but when 2x DIMMs per channel are installed, the system will not POST.
I could just reseat the processor and find out, but I would like to understand the technical details at the implementation level (at least a little better) before just tearing things apart and crossing my fingers.

This is highly processor dependent, we need a block diagram of the system or schematic

Bus loading is also dependent on things like the module's rank and whether your modules are buffered/registered, etc... the modules you've linked are not buffered/registered, the rank is unspecified, and there's no detailled datasheet (yay).

@Attie wow, ok, so maybe I just try the reseat.  I was expecting that the dimms on the same channel were on a bus with chipselect pins or low-bit-address-permutation or something, but that the IO lines were basically the same for the same channel.

It is of course possible to reseat both CPU and DIMMs and get improved signal integrity (either by chance/luck or with cleaning), and this may even get memory to train that previously failed... but unless the cleaning was visibly required, I doubt the result would be stable. If you were designing a mainboard, then I think this question would fit (with a refocus on SI and validation), but as you're discussing consumer equipment, I think it's off-topic. Sorry.

@Attie yes it is consumer equipment, but the question is about DDR5 wiring

A single DDR5 UDIMM has 2x 32-bit sub-channels, each sub-channel has 2x Chip-Select signals, each UDIMM socket therefore gets a separate set of CS signals. Your mainboard has 4x UDIMM sockets, two for each memory channel. If you've confirmed that all of your modules work, and have confirmed that both of the sockets on each memory channel are operational, then why is the wiring in question?

@Attie, only one socket on each memory channel is working.  Trying to understand wiring topology to know if a re-seat is warranted since both channels do work with a single socket populated for each channel.

It's odd that only one is working for each channel - are you confident that the other just doesn't work, and is it the same socket for both channels? ... is this potentially a limitation of your CPU? (I would be quite surprised if you had connectivity issues for one socket on each channel, but nothing else)

@Attie, well an identical system has the same problem, so now I'm suspecting a compatibility issue.  That also confirms that a reseat is unnecessary.  Thanks for the DDR5 feedback, you saved me some time for sure.

What processor are you using? Sometimes they just can't use more than a certain amount of RAM, so if you're trying to cram huge amounts of RAM into the computer it may be that. The motherboard specifies that it supports no more than 256 GB of RAM, so if you have more than that for some reason (that'd be an absurd amount of RAM though), I'd expect issues.

@Hearth, its an AMD 9950X which supports 128GB, and these are 4x 32GB modules with sequential serial numbers.
